# Add Wordpress Custom Taxonomy Link to PAge

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, hook-woocommerce

I created a custom taxonomy under woocommerce products called ‘product type’. I would like to add a link to the product type category to the page meta of the single product page similar to the category link already there.

How can I retrieve the name and link of the product type assigned to the product?

I know it should go in/under

```
<?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

yourtheme/single-product/meta.php

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('product-type');

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
    if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<span class="posted_in">'.$custom_term->name.'</span>';
    }
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I'm not an expert but I think that would work